# getMetrics() from a Scrollview?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, scrollview

How to get Metrics from a ScrollView ? I need it to put my Views (Button, TextView) inside my scrollview and i want to set x and y position. Anybody have an idea ?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't put more than one view into a scroll view.
And you shouldn't use absolute positioning by manually setting x and y.
Try to wrap your views into some layout (looks like it should be LinearLayout with vertical orientation in your case).
Check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html